# Identifier sqrt not detected

Tags: swift, swift3

When I was calculating a square root of a number in my command line using `sqrt(newValue)` it gave back the error `Use of unresolved identifier "sqrt"`.

Is there a new Operator for this or why is it detecting an error?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: make sure to import Darwin

Comment: Btw there is a new method declared on Swift Standard Library called `squareRoot()`. So no need to import anything if you use the new method `newValue.squareRoot()`

Comment: Forgot to mention `squareRoot` is only available to Xcode 9 • Swift 4 or later